# How do i resolve my 500 internal server error at my Php page?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost, internal-server-error

Good to be back but this time i am using php as my code language.
This is definitely new for me and I am still learning.

I have XAMPP: Successfully connected. i was not having any issues
[image: Successfully connected. i was not having any issues]

I have PHP myadmin:does the eye icon means the database connected to my codes and the one will be displayed on my web?

[image: does the eye icon means the database connected to my codes and the one will be displayed on my web?]

I am accessing the https://localhost/live/live
which is inside my htdocs folder:

[image]

am i having wrong connection on my database? is this because on the Xampp that the eye icon is on another folder which is i am not calling in my live folder in htdocs?

Thank you!

Comment: The project is in core PHP or any framework of PHP like (Codeigniter, Laravel) ??

Comment: the first i have or was successfully accessed on my web via local host was under core PHP. But now i installed a framework, Laravel (which is successful installed already with composer) and planning to use that but then, I am trying to run it from the core php. maybe that is where i got wrong?

Comment: Stop laravel server from cmd and then try using core php

Comment: Also, you can look in your webserver error log to see what is logged for the 500 message.

Answer (score 2):

that eye icon don't relevance to your connections statuses. that eye are show you that you have one or more hidden tables in your database. for see what are those or make shown them, click on the eye icon to open one window like this:

[image: hided tables in PMA]

you can now see your hide tables and shown each of them by clicking on "Unhide" link

Comment: Thank you, I have re-installed this and now running. I think there are some codes i needed to check then